# Protobuf-net. Deserialize based on

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

Let's say we have the following three classes:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(FirstType))]
[ProtoInclude(20, typeof(SecondType))]
public class Base
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ClassId {get;set;}
}

public class FirstClass : Base
{
    ...
}

public class SecondClass : Base
{
   ...
}
```

And there's relationship between the class Id (in the base class) and the type of a matching child class. For example,

```
var obj1 = new FirstClass() {ClassId = 1}
var obj2 = new SecondClass() {ClassId = 2}
```

Now let's suppose we have serialized those objects. The question is: is there any good way to deserialize the serialized protobuf based the class Id value by looking over the ClassId field? i.e., if the value of classId in the serailized protobuf is 1, then use FirstClass to deserialize remaining stream bytes.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ProtoInclude, then protobuf-net is already taking care of which subclass to use: that is the entire *point* of ProtoInclude. In some cases it is not possible to use inheritance, in which case there are ways to read the proto-stream via either ProtoReader, or by using a second model which only reads that property, then resetting the source and reading again. There is an example of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572685/23354

Comment: thanks for your answers! one more question: the way to read the proto-stream via ProtoReader is very interesting. It sounds like I can make my own custom converter (like JsonConverter in Json.Net) to be used while being deserialized.

In Protobuf-net, is there any way to pass such custom converter so that while desealizaing objects, that custom converter can be used instead of the default one?

Comment: @soleiljy define "custom converter" in this context? `ProtoReader` and `ProtoWriter` is what the serializer uses under the hood - however, they are not customizable. There is only one way of reading the underlying stream. If you mean "I can write my own engine on top of `ProtoReader`" - sure: have fun. There's an example of a custom `DataTable` serializer here: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/DataTableSerializer